# Syntax Error : unexpected token ':' while using jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a cross domain access. In order to avoid access-control aloow origin issue i used datatype jsonp.. but my ajax call gives syntax error unexpected token ':" .. is there any solutuion for this? My ajax call looks like this :

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: 'http://myserver:myport/application';
data: "",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data){
console.log("Data : " + data);
},
error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) { 
console.log("Error!" + status);
            },
jsonp: 'jsonp',

});
```

Comment: Remove last `,` after `jsonp:'jsonp'`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove last `,` from the ajaxCall and add `,` to the end of your `url` parameter!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://myserver:myport/application'; //<-- add ',' here instead ';'
    data: "",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Data : " + data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error!" + status);
    },
    jsonp: 'jsonp' //<-- comma(,) not needed here remove it!

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is not well formed, options are comma separated, so change this:

```
url: 'http://myserver:myport/application';
```

into this:

```
url: 'http://myserver:myport/application',
```

and remove the last comma after `jsonp` option, it's not needed and can cause errors in old browsers.